# Passing parameters with friendly url - MapPageRoute and Page.Route.Values not working - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, friendly-url

I'm using MapPageRoute on Global.asax and passing a parameter like this:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routecollection)
{
routecollection.MapPageRoute("stringname", "stringpath/{parameter}", "~/Page.aspx");
}
```

Here is the link passing the parameter:

```
<a href='../Page.aspx/19'><img src='image.jpg'></a>;
```

And here is the part to where the parameter is sent:

```
idParameter = Convert.ToInt16(Page.RouteData.Values["parameter"]);
```

From here I pass this id to a function and this function brings a lot of informations from the database, with these informations, the page of the item is built. The problem is that when the informations are being assign, inside a try, it stops halfway through, filling only half of the page and presenting the exception error after it. Before I tried to make friendly urls, this request was being made like this "Page.aspx?parameter=19" and everything worked fine. What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was just a little change I had to make on the code that recieved the parameter. Really thanks!